# Email aliases not coming back from graph API users endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are seeing a few users for which the graph API returns only a primary email despite knowing that there are multiple SMTP addresses configured for these users. We are observing this on the [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint as well as the [Get User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

When using the `$select` parameter to include the `otherMails` and `proxyAddresses` properties, both come back as empty arrays. Microsoft365 admins for the tenant to which these users belong have provided us with screenshots demonstrating that some of these users have at least one email alias configured in addition to their primary email.

I'm curious if there's any scenario in which it would be expected that `otherMails` and `proxyAddresses` would be empty despite the presence of aliases on a user? Or if there's a particular way in which the request to the List/Get users endpoints must be crafted to get these fields to come back non-empty. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#mail-and-proxyaddresses-properties) it seems like a collision between SMTP addresses across directory objects *might* cause this, but I'm certain that's not the case for all of the users for which we're seeing this issue.